# How to compile ant-design-vue specific component strings into regular HTML tags

Tags: html, vue.js, ant-design-vue

I have a html string,but this string is ant-design-vue specific component such as this :

```
  <Form
    name="basic"
    labelCol={{ span: 8 }}
    wrapperCol={{ span: 16 }}
    style={{ maxWidth: 600 }}
    initialValues={{ remember: true }}
    onFinish={onFinish}
    onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
    autoComplete="off"
  >
    <Form.Item<FieldType>
      label="Username"
      name="username"
      rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please input your username!' }]}
    >
      <Input />
    </Form.Item>
  </Form>
```

.I want to set this string to innerHtml of a html element(`document.getElementById('target').innerHtml = thisString`),but browser can't render html string of ant-design-vue specific component,how to compile it to regular HTML tags.

I search with Google but find nothing about this question

Comment: Actually, my propose is get form information from backend and generate form . now  I got an idea,I use v-for and put every form item tag in it,and use v-if with data from backend.

Comment: Have you tried it with dynamic components? https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dynamic-components